# Is Visual Studio 2012's new C++ unit testing framework portable?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, portability, vs-unit-testing-framework

One of the new features of VS2012 I'm interested in is the integrated C++ unit testing framework. However, I don't want to use it if it locks me in to the the Windows / Visual Studio platform. Does anyone know how portable it is?

Comment: As a rule, if you are looking for cross-platform functionality or libraries, it's best to not look to the compiler vendors for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of VS2012 so it's for Windows only.

Comment: Visual Studio is perfectly capable of producing cross platform code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the question is about possibility of usage of framework, not about the output that it can produce.

Comment: It would be cross platform if someone rewrites implementation of namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework. So the questioin I am interested in is if is there somewhere some portable project which implements methods in namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework?